# How to modify generated C# Protobuf enums

Tags: c#, enums, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using `protoc` 3.0.0 beta 3 on Windows to generate C# code from a `.proto` file. There was a change from beta 2 to beta 3 that changed my enum values (for the worse). There was an enum defined like so in the `proto` file:

```
enum AnEnum {
    ABC = 0;
    WORD = 1;
    DEF = 2;
}
```

That now ends up in generated code like this:

```
public enum AnEnum {
    [pbr::OriginalName("ABC")] Abc = 0,
    [pbr::OriginalName("WORD")] Word = 1,
    [pbr::OriginalName("DEF")] Def = 2,
}
```

I'm fine with `Word`, but `Abc` and `Def` are wrong, since they're abbreviations. Is there any way to override particular enum cases (or even all enum cases for a particular enum) to pass through the original value?

Otherwise it looks like I'll have to wrap around the generated enums with my own new ones, but I'd rather not duplicate the definitions.